# How can I convert an ARRAY of INTEGERS into a JSON dict?

Tags: google-bigquery

On BQ, how can I convert a column of type INTEGER that contains an array per row such as the following 2 rows:

```
[1,2,3]
[1,2,3,5,8]
```

to a new column of type JSON that looks like the following corresponding rows:

```
{"1":"1","2":"2","3":"3"}
{"1":"1","2":"2","3":"3","5":"5","8":"8"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below approach

```
SELECT mycol, 
  SAFE.PARSE_JSON('{' || REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(FORMAT('%t', mycol), '[]'), r'(\d+)', r'"\1":"\1"') || '}')
FROM your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Thanks vm

Answer (score 1):

Convert elements in an array to rows using `UNNEST`,  use the optional `WITH OFFSET` clause to return an additional column with the offset for each array element, the reconstruct your JSON using `STRING_AGG`

```
WITH tmp as (
    SELECT '[1,2,3]' as mycol union all
    SELECT '[1,2,3,5,8]' 
)
SELECT mycol, JSON_EXTRACT( '{' || STRING_AGG('"' || (key+1) ||'":"'|| value || '"', ',' ORDER BY key) || '}', '$') AS myjson
FROM tmp, UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(mycol)) AS value
WITH OFFSET AS key
GROUP BY mycol
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: SelVazi thanks vm for your response, wonderful solution. My only issue is that the output column `new_json` is of type STRING not JSON. When trying to convert it with `TO_JSON(new_json)` the output then looks like `"{\"1\":\"1\",\"2\":\"2\",\"3\":\"3\"}"`. Are you aware of a way to result in a JSON column type from this string but without the backslashes?

Comment: Can you try `JSON_EXTRACT( '{' || STRING_AGG('"' || key ||'":"'|| element || '"', ',' ORDER BY key) || '}', '$')`

Comment: Unfortunately the resulting column Type is still STRING

Answer (score 0):

You can convert an ARRAY of INTEGERS into a JSON object using Google BQ by using the `TO_JSON_STRING` function

```
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(ARRAY<INT64>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) as json_string;
```

This will convert the array of integers into a JSON string